# Unable to submit form from JSP to Servlet

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am a beginner at JSP and Servlets. In my application folder structure is as follows:

```
Servlet Class: LearningJSP\src\servlet\UserDetailsServlet.

Jsp file : JSP\Inputform.jsp
```

The code is as follows:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class UserDetails
 */

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/userdetails"})

public class UserDetailsServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UserDetailsServlet()
    {
        super();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");

        javabeans.UserDetailsValue userDetails = new javabeans.UserDetailsValue();
        userDetails.setAge(age);
        userDetails.setName(name);
        userDetails.setSurname(surname);

        request.setAttribute("message", "saved successfully.");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

InputForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please fill up the data for Registration.</h1>
<form action = "/userdetails" method = "GET">
<input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "surname"><br>
<input type = "text" name = "age"><br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Register"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting

> Error 404: Resource not found.

I think there is some mistake in Url in action tag in JSP, but after many trials I coundn't find my mistake.

Please help me to find error.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is it not finding? how did you configure your server/start page?

Comment: I have added JSP name in Web.xml file. When I am running the application on Tomcat server, JSP is getting displayed, after entering form  values, when it should redirect to servlet, it gives me error 404

Comment: Try action="userdetails" without "/".

Comment: I tried with that. When I doing like that the URL patterns comes as follows...                               http://localhost:8081/LearningJSP/JSP/userdetails?name=data&surname=data&age=data @Panagiotis Stoupos

Answer (score 0):

try using  `action = "../userdetails"` .

Comment: I tried with that. When I doing like that the URL patterns comes as follows...                               http://localhost:8081/LearningJSP/JSP/userdetails?name=data&surname=data&age=data

Comment: where have you put you jsp folder? can you paste your project structure?

Comment: structure is as follows:                                                                                                        LearningJSP(project name)WebContent\JSP(folder name)\Inputform.jsp

Comment: if you are you annotation then why you have mapped it again in web.xml?

Comment: Web.xml only contains the welcome-file name. I does not contain any servlet mapping information. You can check in below post, I have copied the code of web.xml (unformatted, though!)

Comment: I have update ans, check it now,

Comment: Hi I tried with package name i.e. "servlet". I gave as follows action = "/servlet/userdetails".. still same result. I even tried complete path i.e. action = "LearningJSP/servlet/userdetails"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `UserDetails.jsp` page directly under the WebContent folder? If not, the Exception is comming from here:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

because the file does not exist at this path:

```
LearningJSP\WebContent\
```

> One good exercise to see all the resources that are being called, would be to

- open the browser
- open up the console (`F12`)
- go to Network
- Click on Start capturing (`CTRL + E` in Chrome)
- refresh the page to see all the resources requested by your page. One of them will have the status 404.

[image: all the resources requested by one page]

Comment: Actually my form is not getting submitted to Servlet at all. I checked it by writing a System.Out.println. Though I changed it to

Comment: @Samkit, check my improved answer, it might help. You can see exactly which resource is not found.

Answer (score -3):

[Your Project Structure should be like this. Click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok0Zn.png)

InputForm.jsp should have form tag as below:

UserDetailsServlet.java doGet method should have:
 `request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/UserDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Note: /JSP/UserDetails.jsp

This is my modified answer, please give me positive votes, if solution works.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LearningJSP</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>InputForm.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: JSP folder structure   Webcontent\JSP\Inputform.jsp

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: People seem to be eager to give -ve comments, lets see what they do when I give a correct answer

Comment: Hey Samkit, your solution is, in InputForm.jsp define form as <form action = "../userdetails" method = "GET"> and in UserDetailsServlet.java : request.getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/UserDetails.jsp").forward(request, response); Note /JSP/UserDetails.jsp

Comment: If my answer is correct, please give positive votes.I am new to stackoverflow, help me to earn positives.

Comment: that was one other mistake in my code. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Guys need positive votes, Rehman and Stultuske